# FirebaseUI using 2 activities for login kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication

FirebaseUIAuth using 2 activities for the login.

Hi guys, good morning, I have a problem.
I use FirebaseUI to authenticate using social networks or email and telephone.
The login is perfect, enter the session in all social networks, everything perfectly.
The problem is when I close session.
When I close session and I want to return to the activity,
It does not return me to the main activity. It stays planted in the second activity and when I minimize the app and I go back again, just there, the login options appear.

I clarify, that the first activity, where are the buttons to login
are created by the same firebaseUI, I mean the first activity is blank.

I think the problem is that I need to use some method in onStart (), onResume (). and I do not know what to put in those methods so that the activity is created again and can execute the startActivityForResult () method
and draw the session buttons.

I tried to remove the finish () method, those who are in the code to not eliminate the first activity, the bad thing is that if I do that,
the first blank activity will appear and the login buttons offered by firebaseUI will not be drawn.

Sorry by the translating - I used a translator. 
I hope my problem has been understood

**First activity**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_firebase_auth)
    if (currentUser != null && auth != null) {
        startActivity(Intent(this@FirebaseAuthActivity, SignedInActivity::class.java))
        finish()
    } else {
        authenticateUser()
    }
}

private fun authenticateUser() {
    startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance()
            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
            .setTheme(R.style.CustomTheme)
            .setLogo(R.drawable.firelogo)
            .setAvailableProviders(getProviderList())
            .setIsSmartLockEnabled(true)
            .build(),
            REQUEST_CODE)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    val response: IdpResponse? = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data)
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            startActivity(Intent(this@FirebaseAuthActivity, SignedInActivity::class.java))
            finish()
            return
        }
    }
}

private fun getProviderList(): List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> {
    val providers = ArrayList<AuthUI.IdpConfig>()
    providers.add(AuthUI.IdpConfig.EmailBuilder().build())
    providers.add(AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build())
    providers.add(AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build())
    providers.add(AuthUI.IdpConfig.TwitterBuilder().build())
    providers.add(AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build())
    return providers
}
```

**Second activity**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signed_in)
    if (currentUser == null) {
        startActivity(Intent(this@SignedInActivity, FirebaseAuthActivity::class.java))
        finish()
    }
    btn_signout.setOnClickListener() {
        signOut()    }
}


private fun signOut() {
    AuthUI.getInstance()
            .signOut(this)
            .addOnCompleteListener{ task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    startActivity(Intent (this@SignedInActivity, FirebaseAuthActivity::class.java))
                    finish()
                } else {
                    //  Report error to user
                }
            }
}
```

Any ideas.

Comment: I forgot to tell you, that in the emulator it runs very well, I do not have that problem there.
Thats weird.

Comment: Please don't format your code as you did and see how it should be done now.

Comment: What do you mean by saying it runs well on an emulator? Are you seeing the problem on a specific device? Have you tried another manufacturer or brand? You also mention that the activity switch appears to be only after you exit and come back to the app? Have you, at that point, debugged and checked that the `signOut()` method was done? There is much detail missing in your question. As it currently is, it's just a wild guess

Comment: When I close session, it sends me to the main activity and the login options provided by FirebaseUI appear it in the emulator, but in the device no. I have a Samsung with Nougat Api 24, I only have that physical device
That's the problem, using the physical device, but this phone is not flashed and is not old. I try to debug that method, checking the debug in AuthUI.getInstance () but I can not interpret the fault. Could you tell me what to look for in the entire debug list? regards

Comment: There is nothing specific to look for in LogCat, what you need to check if the flow of your code. Check what happens with the `task` inside the `autoCompleteListener`, for instance. You don't need to be calling `finish()` to change activities if they are correctly setup with affinities, launch modes, and parenting. A bit more info on that would also be useful

Comment: If I remove the finish, at the moment of closing session, I would send myself to the first activity. And the first one is blank, when I turn it to landscape and then portrait, just there, appear the login options provided by firebase. also when I minimize and return. Let me see the logCat and I warn you that I find, If you refer to the Manifest, the first activity is Launcher, the second does not have any additional parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Move your check for if the current user is signed in to

```
overload fun onStart(){}
```

Or

```
overload fun onResume(){}
```

I can’t remember which since I don’t have my computer in front me but I know it’s one of those two. I had the same problem + sometimes would make me sign in right after I signed in. Moving the check to one of those functions will do the trick(but I can’t remember which) so try both. 
**Edit**
Just wanted to specify when I say check for current user I mean this code.

```
If(currentUser != null){}
```

**Edit**

Ok so I was close... ish. What I got to work was in my main activity initilize the Firebase Auth. Then in onCreate i have a function that gets current user information and lets me use it.

```
    var mAuth: FirebaseAuth? = null
    val RC_SIGN_IN = 123

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer_layout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close)
    drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
    toggle.syncState()
    nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)

    setUserProfile()
}

fun setUserProfile(){
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    val mUser = mAuth?.currentUser

    tvEmail.text = mUser?.email
    tvDisplayName.text = mUser?.displayName
}
```

In onStart() what I did is check if user is not signed in I force them to sign in after forcing the user to sign in the return point is the onStart method so then i run setUserProfile() again. What happened was that if I didnt do that in both on create and onStart then I would only be able to get the currentUser data if i specificly signed in that time. otherwise there would be no errors but no currentUser data.

```
    override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    if (mAuth!!.currentUser == null){
        iForced()
    }
    setUserProfile()

}
```

my function that forces user to signIn iForced()

```
    fun iForced(){
    startActivityForResult(
        AuthUI.getInstance()
                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                .build(),
        RC_SIGN_IN)
}
```

I hope that wasnt to confusing.

Comment: let me try it, to see how it responds

Comment: I could solve the problem of the activity,
so that I return to activity A and
which displays the firebaseUI interface,
with the login buttons.

Now I'm trying to solve, the method
`onBackPressed()`

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the solution to the problem I had, something uncomfortable, but I solve the problem,
something strange I must say,
was the method `loginOut()` and the `deleteAccount()` method
inside the `addOnCompleteListener` method
I put a conditional -> 
`if (task.isSuccessful)`
I inverted it -> `if (!task.isSuccessful)`
this caused 2 behaviors

**The first -** is that on the device finally when
I press the button close session now if
he sent me to the first activity,
and it shows me the buttons that FirebaseUI offers

**the second -** is that the opposite happens in the emulator,
of what previously happened on the device
now it happens in the emulator

So I decided to remove that conditional and it's a gem
both on the device and the emulator
they return me to the first activity,
with the buttons that firebaseUI offers

then the methods will leave them like this:

`private fun signOut() {
     AuthUI.getInstance()
         .signOut(this@SignedInActivity)
         .addOnCompleteListener{
             startActivity(
                 Intent(this@SignedInActivity,
                     FirebaseAuthActivity::class.java))
             finish()
         }
}`

`private fun deleteAccount() {
     AuthUI.getInstance()
         .delete(this@SignedInActivity)
         .addOnCompleteListener{
             startActivity(
                 Intent(this@SignedInActivity,
                     FirebaseAuthActivity::class.java))
             finish()
         }
}`

the problem now is the onBackPressed () method

Even if someone has a better solution, welcome, that conditional helps to see if there was an error.

Thank you Vahalaru and Chisko for your answers,
they helped me in something.